# new columns not showing on datatables js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datatables

i'm trying to add new columns to the datatables but they are not showing
i add the header of both of them.

Here's the html part:

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
       <table class="display dataTables table-bordered" cellspacing="0" id="userteams_table">
                 <thead class="thead">
                         <tr>
                                 <th class="text-center">
                                    Team Name
                                 </th>
                                 <th class="text-center">
                                     Team Country
                                 </th>
                                 <th class="text-center">
                                      Fan Type
                                 </th>
                                 <th class="text-center">
                                       Global Rating
                                 </th>
                                <th class="text-center">
                                       Local Rating
                                </th>
                               <th class="text-center">
                                      Remove
                               </th>
                       </tr>
            </thead>
     </table>
```

Here's the datatable columns part in js:

```
"columns": [
{ "data": "Name" },
{ "data": "Country" },
{ "data": "FanType" },
{ "data": "GlobalRating" },
{ "data": "LocalRating" },
{ "data": "TeamID" }
```

I also attach an image of the outcome:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

the server side fills all fields.

Thank you for your help

**UPDATE**
I added the full datatable use in js

```
 function loadUserTeamsTable(data) {

    dt2 = $('#userteams_table').DataTable({
        "order": [[0, "desc"]],
        "bStateSave": true,
        "fnStateSaveParams": function (oSettings, sValue) {
            /* $.cookie("Status", $("#Status").val(), { expires: 7 });
             $.cookie("TemplateID", $("#TemplateID").val().replace('-', ''), { expires: 7 });
             $.cookie("FamilyID", $("#FamilyID").val(), { expires: 7 });
             $.cookie("LastTreatmentByID", $("#LastTreatmentByID").val(), { expires: 7 });*/
        },
        "fnStateLoadParams": function (oSettings, oData) {
            /*$("#Status").val($.cookie("Status"));
            $("#TemplateID").val($.cookie("TemplateID"));
            $("#FamilyID").val($.cookie("FamilyID"));
            $("#LastTreatmentByID").val($.cookie("LastTreatmentByID"));*/
        },
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
            "aButtons": []
        },
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "language": {
            "sProcessing": "Processing...",
            "sLengthMenu": "show _MENU_ items",
            "sZeroRecords": "No Match were found",
            "sInfo": "_START_ To _END_ From _TOTAL_ Teams",
            "sInfoEmpty": "0 To 0 From 0 Teams",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(מסונן מסך _MAX_  רשומות)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sSearch": "Team Free Search:",
            "sUrl": "",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "First",
                "sPrevious": "Previous",
                "sNext": "Next",
                "sLast": "Last"
            }
        },
        "serverSide": true,
        "orderMulti": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Users/FilterUserTeamsData",
            "data": function (d) {
                d.jsona = JSON.stringify(new JsonUserTeamSearch());
                d.freeText = $("#userteams_table_filter input").val();
            },
            "type": "POST",
            "dataType": "json",
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        },
        //"aaData": data,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Name" },
            { "data": "Country" },
            { "data": "FanType" },
            { "data": "GlobalRating" },
            { "data": "LocalRating" },
            { "data": "TeamID" }

        ],        
        "columnDefs": [
            { "width": "10%", "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] },
            { "type": "date", "targets": [1] }
        ],
        "fnInitComplete": function () {
            $($('.panel')[1]).append($('.DTTT_container'));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the ViewModel that you use to fill the rows?

Comment: they fill with ajax call with json, i added only global and local location before them it was working fine

Comment: Then please show the JSON Model used for the call. I assume there is a typo somewhere, e.g. `TeamID` vs. `TeamId`.

Comment: The lines are added like this: teams.Add(new JsonUserTeams { GlobalRating = GetGlobalRating(team.T_Teams.ID), LocalRating = GetLocalRating(team.T_Teams.ID, team.T_Users.CountryID), TeamID = id, FanType = fan, Country = team.T_Teams.T_Countries.Name, Name = team.T_Teams.Name });  global and local rating functions returns "1"  than i'm sending the json where data is the list of teams var jsonResult = Json(new { draw = draw, recordsTotal = totalRecords, recordsFiltered = totalRecords, data = teams, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });

Comment: The code is ok i needed to force refresh on the browser Thank you for your time

Comment: Glad you found the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the datatables not showing any columns check the following:
1. add headers in the table
2. check for typos between the data from the server and what each column bind to
3. force refresh of the browser (ctrl F5)